# FreeBSD add password-based ftp authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, freebsd, sshd

Please help me with my issue on FreeBSD server. I need to have ftp access to the server. No matter which type - ftp or sftp. Just a file transfer.

I cannot configure server. I've tried to use ftp, to configure sshd - but result the same - FileZilla response "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)". Google says it means that server only set to use public/private keys for authorization, but I need to use password-based authentication.

Please tell me how I can turn on password authentication. Last server admin is lost so I don't know what configuration surprises he has left for me.

My sshd_config:

```
Port 2233
#AllowGroups wheel
PidFile /var/run/freesshd.pid
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes
UsePAM no
Protocol 2
PasswordAuthentication yes
Subsystem   sftp   internal-sftp
```

Comment: did you restart sshd server?

Comment: Of cource. I even try to restart whole server but result the same.

Comment: Finally I've left the idea about password authentication, added PubkeyAuthentication yes to sshd_config to authenticate with keys